# How much safer is it really to replace the default account with a new account?

Tags: authentication, account-security

When getting a new appliance, be it a firewall or or the like, how much safer is it really to replace the default admin account/username with a differently-named account but with same privilege level?

In my mind, the only scenario in which this is of any benefit is making the replacement account a complex username?

Otherwise, replacing "Admin" with "ourcompany_admin" or the like simply buys you only a small amount of extra time if brute-forced?

Comment: Theoretically this is security by obsecurity, but practically, it's very useful against the millions of scanners on the internet...

Answer (score 4):

By creating a new administration account (and disabling the default administration account) or renaming the default administration account, an attacker would need to first figure out the name of the administration account to be able to begin brute-forcing the account.

Being generous to the question, take [exploit code from the recent CVE-2016-6210](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jul/51) from OpenSSHD as an example: the attacker needs to have guesses for what the usernames could be to see if the user is real or not. In reality (since that was a vulnerability in the OpenSSHD), authentication mechanisms *usually* don't provide a way to determine if a user is real or not -- the attempted logon either authenticates and allows you in *or* the attempted logon fails.

Changing the default administrator username adds to security through obscurity (many people don't subscribe to the concept). This really only helps with brute-forcing attempts, because once an attacker is able to exploit the authentication mechanism -- using things like code injection, etc -- the attacker is able to bypass the need for a real username.

Answer (score 3):

Setting up a separate administrator account creates a new user ID in the system (and that has greater effect on the security than just a different account name).

Theoretically it might protect you from a vulnerability in the software if a developer took the shortcut and made an explicit reference to the default administrator account ID somewhere in the code.

Also when you set up a new account you must assign the permissions. If you refrain from adding full permissions in bulk, but assign only the necessary ones, you end up using a less privileged (thus more secure) account.

There were cases of systems in which the built-in administrator always had greater privileges than those created on demand. Particularly it might have a right to override/reset any imposed restriction.

Finally, in case of a compromise, it is much easier to block or revoke the permissions to the manually-created administrator account than the built-in one.